# Decoding the IE9 user agent

Tags: internet-explorer-9, user-agent

I installed IE9 in a Windows 7 virtual machine, and was surprised to see this user agent:

`Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; BOIE9;ENUSMSNIP)`

In particular, the last two keys **BOIE9** and **ENUSMSNIP** look very spammy. I'm used to seeing toolbars and add-ins register themselves at the end of the user agent like that, but this is on a virgin install of Windows 7 with no other software.

They're defined in the registry here:

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\User Agent\PostPlatform`

That key has a value of `IEAK`, which is apparently the [Internet Explorer Administrators Kit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/bb219517) which [according to Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218933) sends a custom user agent string.

#### But why?

I'm guessing that `BOIE9` is stands for "Bing on IE9". It's the only active Add-On:

[image]

As for `ENUSMSNIP`, I'm at a loss. My guesses are:

- ENUS = Locale, which for me is EN-US ("US English")
- MS = Microsoft
- NIP = ???

I tried changing my locale to EN-GB, but the user agent didn't update nor did the registry. So it appears it's only at the time of install that it matters (if I'm even right about ENUS).

Does anyone know what these two user agent keys represent?

Or, care to share what your IE9 user agent is, and maybe we can piece it together ourselves?

Comment: Did you install the "Bing Branded" version of the browser? These keys aren't in a stock install. FWIW, they're also not sent in the HTTP header except in the Compatibility View mode. I'm guessing the proper breakdown is [ENUS, MSN, IP], where ENUS is the locale of the package.

Comment: You know what? I installed IE9 from an advertisement at the top of msn.com the first time I loaded Internet Explorer. (MSN.com being the default homepage for IE on Windows 7.) I'm going to install from Windows Update instead and see if I get the stock user agent.

Comment: @Portman, did you ever determine anything more about this? #1 on a search for ENUSMSNIP. (Just ran into this today from one of our users.)

Comment: @JamesSkemp: Negative. I was unable to reproduce ENUSMSNIP ever again in any Virtual Machines!

Answer (score 2):

You have the right of it, mostly. I think this is a result of emulating Firefox/Chrome's newer anti-phishing features.

```
EN_US : Locale (US English)
MS    : Microsoft
NIP   : Network Intrusion Prevention
```